Samba, Apache WebDAV and delegation
I'm struggling with setup over the month and ideas are almost finish. Maybe I'll start by describing the infrastructure.
The Infrastructure
So the basic idea is to connect to Apache WebDAV with SSO through built-in Windows. Linux, Mac client. Everything worked fine in this scenario:
3. Active Directory ←-----------→ 2. Apache  ←-------------→ 1. Client

Client: Ubuntu desktop - realmd, adcli, sssd* packages have been installed
Apache 2.4 v. 2.4.62 on Fedora Linux 40 with installed GSSAPI module
Active Directory - Samba v. 4.21.0 on Rocky Linux 9

I have samba installed by default, so the default Kerberos server is Heimdal Kerberos.
But in my case, at the end environment will be look like this:

                         | ←-------------→ 2. Apache (webdav1) ←----------> 1. Client 1
                         |
                         |      
3. Active Directory ←---→| ←-------------→ 2. Apache (webdav2) ←----------→ 1. Client 2
                         |
                         |
                         | ←-------------→ 2. Apache (webdav3) ←----------→ 1. Client 3

Each of these Apache servers will have a different URL. I'm not very familiar with Kerberos, but it turns out that each Apache server needs to have its own Service Principal Name (SPN): HTTP/webdav1, HTTP/webdav2, HTTP/webdv3 for Kerberos, after adding SPN to domain user account I need to export keytab file and distribute it to all Apache servers.
And here is a problem, because I will not have access to domain controller, only what I will have is a SPN, a user with delegation enabled. So in theory it should look like this:

                                                   | ←-----→ 2. Apache (webdav1) ←---→ 1. Client 1
                                                   |
                                                   |        
4. Active Directory ←----→ 3. Apache (auth) ←----→ | ←-----→ 2. Apache (webdav2) ←---→ 1. Client 2
                                                   |
                                                   |
                                                   | ←-----→ 2. Apache (webdav3) ←---→ 1. Client 3

So on 4. Apache (auth) I will be able to install MIT Kerberos and enable GssapiUseS4U2Proxy option in http *.conf file. But I don't know how to configure everything:

How to configure 3. Apache (auth)? I read in GSSAPI_mod documentation that I need two keytab files (GssapiUseS4U2Proxy section): one for "connection" between 4. Active Directory and 3. Apache(auth) and second keytab for clients - "connections" between 3. Apache(auth) and 2. Apache(webdavx).
Should I create a principal in 3. Apache(auth), principal with delegation enabled for 2. Apache(webdavx) services?
How do I configure 2. Apache (webdavx)? How do I set up krb5.conf, should I point to domain or to 3. Apache(auth) in krb5.conf?

What I did:
Approach one:
I have been installed Samba with default setup, so Samba has been installed with Heimdal Kerberos. I was able to connect 1. Client to domain, but I wasn't able to setup delegation. There is command samba-tool delegation, I was able to add flag for-any-protocol, does it mean Set/unset UF_TRUSTED_TO_AUTHENTICATE_FOR_DELEGATION (S4U2Proxy) for an account. When I tried to add add-principal flag (does it mean Add a principal to msDS-AllowedToActOnBehalfOfOtherIdentity that may delegate to an account.) I had an error "Principal not found". Now i don't know which flag i should use, this is result of samba-tool --help command:
Usage: samba-tool delegation <subcommand>

Delegation management.


Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --color=always|never|auto
                        use colour if available (default: auto)


Available subcommands:
  add-principal     - Add a principal to msDS-AllowedToActOnBehalfOfOtherIdentity that may delegate to an account.
  add-service       - Add a service principal to msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo so that an account may delegate to it.
  del-principal     - Delete a principal from msDS-AllowedToActOnBehalfOfOtherIdentity that may no longer delegate to an account.
  del-service       - Delete a service principal from msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo so that an account may no longer delegate to it.
  for-any-protocol  - Set/unset UF_TRUSTED_TO_AUTHENTICATE_FOR_DELEGATION (S4U2Proxy) for an account.
  for-any-service   - Set/unset UF_TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION for an account.
  show              - Show the delegation setting of an account.

for samba-tool delegation add-principal:
Usage: samba-tool delegation add-principal <accountname> <principal> [options]

Add a principal to msDS-AllowedToActOnBehalfOfOtherIdentity that may delegate
to an account.


Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -H URL, --URL=URL     LDB URL for database or target server
  --color=always|never|auto
                        use colour if available (default: auto)

  Credentials Options:
    --simple-bind-dn=DN
                        DN to use for a simple bind
    --password=PASSWORD
                        Password
    -U USERNAME, --username=USERNAME
                        Username
    -W WORKGROUP, --workgroup=WORKGROUP
                        Workgroup
    -N, --no-pass       Don't ask for a password
    --ipaddress=IPADDRESS
                        IP address of server
    -P, --machine-pass  Use stored machine account password
    --use-kerberos=desired|required|off
                        Use Kerberos authentication
    --use-krb5-ccache=KRB5CCNAME
                        Kerberos Credentials cache
    -A AUTHFILE, --authentication-file=AUTHFILE
                        Authentication file
    -k KERBEROS, --kerberos=KERBEROS
                        DEPRECATED: Migrate to --use-kerberos

  Samba Common Options:
    -s FILE, --configfile=FILE
                        Configuration file
    -d DEBUGLEVEL, --debuglevel=DEBUGLEVEL
                        debug level
    --option=OPTION     set smb.conf option from command line
    --realm=REALM       set the realm name

  Version Options:
    -V, --version       Display version numer

Maybe just for-any-protocol I should use?
Approach two:
I have been installed samba with MIT-Kerberos, so during the configuration I added those flags: --with-system-mitkrb5 --with-experimental-mit-ad-dc. Here I can't join the client to the domain, this is the result:
sudo realm join -v mydomain.internal
[sudo] password for user jimmy: 
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.mydomain.internal
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 172.16.0.1
 * Successfully discovered: mydomain.internal
Password for Administrator: 
 * Unconditionally checking packages
 * Resolving required packages
 * LANG=C /usr/sbin/adcli join --verbose --domain mydomain.internal --domain-realm MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL --domain-controller 172.16.0.1 --login-type user --login-user Administrator --stdin-password
 * Using domain name: mydomain.internal
 * Calculated computer account name from fqdn: UBUNTU
 * Using domain realm: mydomain.internal
 * Sending NetLogon ping to domain controller: 172.16.0.1
 * Received NetLogon info from: dc1.mydomain.internal
 * Wrote out krb5.conf snippet to /var/cache/realmd/adcli-krb5-SkorFJ/krb5.d/adcli-krb5-conf-pTrVz4
 ! Couldn't authenticate as: Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL: Preauthentication failed
adcli: couldn't connect to mydomain.internal domain: Couldn't authenticate as: Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL: Preauthentication failed
 ! Failed to join the domain
realm: Failed to join the domain

On Kerberos side:
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): INFO: 

Current debug levels:
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   all: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   tdb: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   printdrivers: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   lanman: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   smb: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   rpc_parse: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   rpc_srv: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   rpc_cli: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   passdb: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   sam: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   auth: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   winbind: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   vfs: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   idmap: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   quota: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   acls: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   locking: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   msdfs: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dmapi: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   registry: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   scavenger: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dns: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   ldb: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   tevent: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   auth_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   auth_json_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   kerberos: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   drs_repl: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   smb2: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   smb2_credits: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_json_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_password_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_password_json_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_transaction_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_transaction_json_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_group_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_group_json_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   ldapsrv: 5
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): Processing section "[sysvol]"
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): Processing section "[netlogon]"
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): Processing section "[users]"
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): pm_process() returned Yes
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): schema_fsmo_init: we are master[yes] updates allowed[no]
Oct 04 14:04:09 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): Loaded
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](Error): preauth pkinit failed to initialize: PKINIT initialization failed: No pkinit_identity supplied for realm MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](Error): preauth spake failed to initialize: No SPAKE preauth groups configured
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): setting up network...
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): setsockopt(16,IPV6_V6ONLY,1) worked
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): setsockopt(18,IPV6_V6ONLY,1) worked
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): set up 4 sockets
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): lpcfg_load: refreshing parameters from /usr/local/samba/etc/smb.conf
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): Processing section "[global]"
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): INFO: Current debug levels:
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   all: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   tdb: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   printdrivers: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   lanman: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   smb: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   rpc_parse: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   rpc_srv: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   rpc_cli: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   passdb: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   sam: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   auth: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   winbind: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   vfs: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   idmap: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   quota: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   acls: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   locking: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   msdfs: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dmapi: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   registry: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   scavenger: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dns: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   ldb: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   tevent: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   auth_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   auth_json_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   kerberos: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   drs_repl: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   smb2: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   smb2_credits: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_json_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_password_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_password_json_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_transaction_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_transaction_json_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_group_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   dsdb_group_json_audit: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info):   ldapsrv: 5
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): Processing section "[sysvol]"
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): Processing section "[netlogon]"
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): Processing section "[users]"
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): pm_process() returned Yes
Oct 04 14:04:10 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): commencing operation
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): authsam_account_ok: Checking SMB password for user Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): logon_hours_ok: No hours restrictions for user Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): AS_REQ (6 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), camellia256-cts-cmac(26), camellia128-cts-cmac(25)}) 172.16.0.10: NEEDED_PREAUTH: Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL for krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL, Additional pre-authentication required
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): authsam_account_ok: Checking SMB password for user Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): logon_hours_ok: No hours restrictions for user Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): kdb_samba_db_issue_pac: Generate PAC for AS-REQ [client=Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL, flags=0x000040]
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): AS_REQ (6 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), camellia256-cts-cmac(26), camellia128-cts-cmac(25)}) 172.16.0.10: ISSUE: authtime 1728043476, etypes {rep=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), tkt=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), ses=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18)}, Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL for krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): sync interval is 14
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): authsam_calculate_lastlogon_sync_interval: randomised sync interval is 13 (-1)
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): lastLogonTimestamp is 133724574086692640
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): old timestamp is 133724574086692640, threshold 133713938765734640, diff 10635320958000
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): lastLogonTimestamp is 133724574086692640
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): old timestamp is 133724574086692640, threshold 133713938765784260, diff 10635320908380
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): DSDB Change [Modify] at [Fri, 04 Oct 2024 14:04:36.580718 CEST] status [Success] remote host [Unknown] SID [S-1-5-18] DN [CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=internal] attributes [replace: lastLogon [133725170765784260] replace: logonCount [15]]
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): {"timestamp": "2024-10-04T14:04:36.581026+0200", "type": "dsdbChange", "dsdbChange": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 0}, "statusCode": 0, "status": "Success", "operation": "Modify", "remoteAddress": null, "performedAsSystem": false, "userSid": "S-1-5-18", "dn": "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=internal", "transactionId": "9b53f5e9-9433-41cd-abab-6743322323b3", "sessionId": "10ba4009-13ed-4d29-969b-95b1da6a58f8", "attributes": {"lastLogon": {"actions": [{"action": "replace", "values": [{"value": "133725170765784260"}]}]}, "logonCount": {"actions": [{"action": "replace", "values": [{"value": "15"}]}]}}}}
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): descriptor_prepare_commit: changes: num_registrations=0
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): descriptor_prepare_commit: changes: num_registered=0
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): descriptor_prepare_commit: changes: num_toplevel=0
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): descriptor_prepare_commit: changes: num_processed=0
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): descriptor_prepare_commit: objects: num_processed=0
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): descriptor_prepare_commit: objects: num_skipped=0
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): kdb_samba_db_issue_pac: Update PAC for TGS-REQ [client=Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL, server=DC1$@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL, flags=00000000]
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): dsdb_search_dn: flags=0x00000010 <SID=S-1-18-1> -> Base-DN '<SID=S-1-18-1>' not found (No such object)
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): dsdb_search_dn: flags=0x00000010 <SID=S-1-5-21-0-0-0-497> -> Base-DN '<SID=S-1-5-21-0-0-0-497>' not found (No such object)
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): TGS_REQ (6 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), camellia256-cts-cmac(26), camellia128-cts-cmac(25)}) 172.16.0.10: ISSUE: authtime 1728043476, etypes {rep=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), tkt=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), ses=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18)}, Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL for DC1$@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): closing down fd 19
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): kdb_samba_db_issue_pac: Update PAC for TGS-REQ [client=Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL, server=kadmin/changepw@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL, flags=00000000]
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): dsdb_search_dn: flags=0x00000010 <SID=S-1-18-1> -> Base-DN '<SID=S-1-18-1>' not found (No such object)
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): dsdb_search_dn: flags=0x00000010 <SID=S-1-5-21-0-0-0-497> -> Base-DN '<SID=S-1-5-21-0-0-0-497>' not found (No such object)
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): TGS_REQ (6 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), camellia256-cts-cmac(26), camellia128-cts-cmac(25)}) 172.16.0.10: ISSUE: authtime 1728043476, etypes {rep=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), tkt=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), ses=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18)}, Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL for kadmin/changepw@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL
Oct 04 14:04:36 dc1.mydomain.internal krb5kdc[117927](info): closing down fd 19

Log info about joining to domain begin with line authsam_account_ok: Checking SMB password for user Administrator@MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL.
When I typed date on Client and AD server, time is the same.
kdc.conf:
[kdcdefaults]
        kdc_ports = 88
        kdc_tcp_ports = 88
        kadmind_port = 464
        restrict_anonymous_to_tgt = true

[realms]
        MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL = {
                master_key_type = aes256-cts
                default_principal_flags = +preauth
        }

        mydomain.internal = {
                master_key_type = aes256-cts
                default_principal_flags = +preauth
        }

        MYDOMAIN = {
                master_key_type = aes256-cts
                default_principal_flags = +preauth
        }

[dbmodules]
        db_module_dir = /usr/local/samba/lib/krb5/plugins/kdb

        MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL = {
                db_library = samba
        }

        mydomain.internal = {
                db_library = samba
        }

        MYDOMAIN = {
                db_library = samba
        }

[logging]
        kdc = FILE:/usr/local/samba/var/mit_kdc.log
        admin_server = FILE:/usr/local/samba/var/mit_kadmin.log

Domain server krb5.conf:
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL
        dns_lookup_realm = false
        dns_lookup_kdc = true
        permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192 aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128 aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96 camellia256-cts-cmac camellia128-cts-cmac

[realms]
MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL = {
        default_domain = mydomain.internal
        kdc = dc1.mydomain.internal
        admin_server = dc1.mydomain.internal
}

[domain_realm]
        dc1 = MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL
        .mydomain.internal = MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL
        mydomain.internal = MYDOMAIN.INTERNAL

I saw few movies how Kerberos works, those all Kerberos Ticket Granting Ticket, Ticket Granting Service, Service Principal Name and so on. But delegation for me it's quite mysterious.
Anyone can help me, explain how all this stuff works? Which approach I should use?
